# Local git server (Bonobo git server) trying to clone a repository throw me an error

Tags: asp.net, git, iis, git-svn, bonobo

On my machine, the git client version is 2.11.1.windows.1
and the server is Bonobo Git Server 5.2.0.0

In the command prompt commands show me this error *"/info/rafs not valid: is this a git repository"* after trying to clone a repository.

I went to the official site in the question section and find this

> fatal: http: /info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
>
> This is a git client way of saying that it didn’t receive git stream as a response from a server. That usually means, that there has been an error on the server side.
>
> To determine what type of error it is, view the log file located at App_Data/Bonobo.Git.Server.Errors.log.

Inside the errors.log.txt file i see the error:

```
w3wp.exe Error: 0 : Error occured and caught in Global.asax - System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at Bonobo.Git.Server.MvcApplication.Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Well, this was weird and not much effort, I opened the IIS on the server and restart the Bonobo WebSite in the IIS. After that everything starts working.

Comment: Have you considered reporting this as an issue? Seems like a minor bug, maybe even a race condition.

Comment: I have the same problem with Bonobo.Git.Server and Visual studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

This type of error, also reported in [jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server issue 657](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/657), is supposed *not* to happen with Bonobo 6.x, released later in 2017 (6.0, 6.1 or 6.2, all in 2017). There is no 6.3 or 6.4.

You would need to check if the issue persists with any Bonobo 6.X, including the 6.5 (April 2019).